# is my nginx config correct?

Tags: nginx

hi im trying to run my Ruby on rails app in nginx using
`passenger start -e production`

but it is missing the `cache: [HEAD /] miss`

im guessing this i dont have actualy a file in public sorry for this question this may be to easy to answer and when i route to www.tock.com it renders a live page in the internet :(

```
  server {
         listen 80;
         server_name www.tock.com;
         passenger_enabled on;
         root /home/led/Aptana\ Studio\ 3\ Workspace/djors/public;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you point the webserver, nginx in this case, you need your DNS to match the location.  If this is your production server, then you need DNS records to point www.tock.com to your server.

If this is your development or local machine, you probably don't want to name your server something that will overwrite the public DNS records.  For example, I name all of my apps in my local nginx config like the following:

server_name  my_app_name.local

Once you've given it a name, you'll need to add "my_app_name.local" to your hosts file (your local DNS records).  Your hosts file should now have entries like below.

127.0.0.1  localhost

127.0.0.1  my_app_name.local

Restart nginx, and you can now goto my_app_name.local in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of passenger and nginx conf all together, as it looks like you are doing this locally and if you want named links (as opposed to just running `bundle exec rails server`; use [Pow](http://pow.cx) to facilitate this. Personally, i'm a rails server guy, but ymmv.